# Resque job fails with "Broken pipe @ io_write - <STDOUT>" (Errno::EPIPE) when writing to STDOUT

Tags: ruby-on-rails, resque

We've been running background jobs using Resque for several years now but recently started getting failed jobs with the following error message and I'm not sure what changed with our code or our environment to be causing this.

```
Errno::EPIPE
Broken pipe @ io_write - <STDOUT>
```

We get this whenever the jobs call puts (which obviously writes to STDOUT).

Can anyone please help shed some light on this?